# APK built by xamarin on mac is not installing

Tags: android, xamarin, apk

I'm building an android app using Xamarin studio on mac. when debugging on real device I have no problem but when I build an APK , xamarin build and sign the app successfully but with this warning :

> No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped.
>   Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after
>   the signer certificate's expiration date (2041-03-07) or after any
>   future revocation date.

I cannot Install this App on a device facing this error : `Application not Installed`
(I should mention that for building this app I'm using a keystore created on windows before.)
please help me to fix this issue.
Thanks

I'm using:

xamarin studio 4.2.3 
Xamarin.Android Version: 4.12.1 
java version "1.7.0_51"

Comment: Do you still have a version of the same package with the debug certificate installed?  That would block installing a version with a release key.  You should check the logcat for more informative install failure messages.

Comment: No. I uninstalled that before trying to install the APK.

Comment: Ok.  If nothing else you can always strip the certificates from the apk with zip file tools and then sign it from the command line with jarsigner, effectively bypassing Xamarin.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is your Java version. Make sure to use Java 1.6.

See this post for more info: http://developer.nickaustinlee.com/2014/03/05/android-application-not-installed-warning/

**TL;DR**

- Install Java 1.6
- Find Java Home for 1.6:

  ```
  $ /usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.6*'
  ```
- Go to Xamarin Preferences (cmd+,) => SDK Locations => Android => set Java SDK.

Sincerely,
—Kaji

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by temporarily switching to Java 1.6 just for building the release archive:

```
sudo cp -R /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk
sudo mv /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk ~/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk
java -version   // shows java version "1.6.0_65" yay!!
```

Do my build without the certificate and timestamped errors. And revert back to Java 8:

```
sudo mv ~/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk
```